# is there a way to get the full path of a result in a jmespath query?

Tags: python, json, jmespath

As an example, I have this json

```
{
  "machines": [
    {"name": "a", "state": "running"},
    {"name": "b", "state": "stopped"},
    {"name": "b", "state": "running"}
  ]
}
```

and my query is `machines[?state=='stopped'].name` which gives the result of `["b"]`

but instead I want to get the path of that result e.g. `machines[1]` or `machines[1].name`

I know this can be done with jsonpath-ng in python, but I want to use jmespath.